# Vue keeps updating other data arrays

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am having some odd behaviour on my component. I have a list of buttons and when clicked each is supposed to be removed from the DOM by removing it from the array. In this case I am using the function `removeItem` and passing it the index of the item. That works fine and it is being removed from the array `abc[]` but what is unexpected is that the same item is being removed from another array `xxzz[]`

```
<template>
    <button v-for="(item, index) in abc" @click="removeItem(index)">{{ item.name }}</button>
</template

export default {
data: () => ({
  abc: [],
  xxzz: [],
}),
methods: {
  removeItem(index){
    this.abc.splice(index, 1);
  },
},
created(){
  var vm = this;
  let formData = new FormData();
  axios({
      url: '/get/items', 
      method: 'post',
      data: formData
    })
    .then(function (response) {
      if(response.status == 200){
        vm.abc = response.data.items;
        vm.xxzz = response.data.items;
      }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: Do you mean `xxzz`, or is there an `xxyy` item defined somewhere else?

Comment: I wonder if perhaps `abc` and `xxzz` are actually the same object because you are making them from the same source. Could you try building `xxzz` with `Object.assign( {} , response.data.items )` to see if that helps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are setting both items to the same array:

```
    vm.abc = response.data.items;
    vm.xxzz = response.data.items;
```

Assignment of objects is done by reference. In this case, `abc` and `xxzz` both refer to the same underlying array. When you modify it in one, you modify it in the other. You probably want to [make a copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486085/copying-array-by-value-in-javascript).